# count with union query not works

Tags: plsql

I'm doing a loop to can see if exits some register in a query with union all. I've done these:

```
DECLARE
COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
FOR I IN (SELECT CALENDAR FROM DF_CALENDAR) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I.CALENDAR);
        SELECT COUNT(CONF_CAL) into CUENTA FROM (
                SELECT CONF_CAL from JOB j
                where CONF_CAL IS NOT NULL 
                UNION
                select DAYS_CAL from  JOB j
                where  DAYS_CAL  IS NOT NULL 
                UNION
                select weeks_cal from  JOB j
                where  weeks_cal  IS NOT NULL) WHERE CONF_CAL='I.CALENDAR';

                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COUNT);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CALENDAR ...'|| I.CALENDAR || ' COUNT NUMBER ' || COUNT);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Allwas the count variable shows me 0 but when I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(CONF_CAL) FROM (
                SELECT CONF_CAL from JOB j
                where CONF_CAL IS NOT NULL 
                UNION
                select DAYS_CAL from  JOB j
                where  DAYS_CAL  IS NOT NULL 
                UNION
                select weeks_cal from  JOB j
                where  weeks_cal  IS NOT NULL) WHERE CONF_CAL='ALLDAYS'
```

it shows me count(conf_cal) = 1.

I can't understand why with loop dont works. Someone could help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not have to do anything with the loop.

I think `WHERE CONF_CAL='I.CALENDER'` is interpreted as a string and not as a column value.

Try to remove the `'`:

```
WHERE CONF_CAL=I.CALENDER
```

Answer (score 0):

A typo perhaps ?

```
 COUNT(CONF_CAL) into CUENTA
```

Should be:

```
 COUNT(CONF_CAL) into COUNT
```

You are declaring and printing the variable `COUNT` , not `CUENTA` .

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
SELECT dfc.calendar,
       COUNT(cc.conf_cal) count_cal
FROM   df_calendar dfc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT conf_cal
                        FROM   job
                        WHERE  conf_cal IS NOT NULL
                        UNION
                        SELECT days_cal
                        FROM   job
                        WHERE  days_cal IS NOT NULL
                        UNION
                        SELECT weeks_cal
                        FROM   job
                        WHERE  weeks_cal IS NOT NULL) cc
         ON (dfc.calendar = cc.conf_cal)
GROUP BY dfc.calendar;
```

?